# Socket.io: Check authentication on every event or connection

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I would like to make sure a user is logged in before they are sending chats. To do this, should I use a authentication middleware that triggers on every connection or use a middleware that trigger on each event?

I am worried if I use the former, the user can sign in then signout (without losing the connection) and continue to send messages while not logged in).

However, looking through all the different stackoverflow posts, no one has mentioned this issue. Can anyone tell me what approach is commonly used?

Comment: How does your sign in and sign out work?  Is it done over socket.io or done over http in the web page before the socket.io connection is made?  If it's done over http, then you could just close all socket.io connections for that user when they sign out and that would prevent what you're concerned about.  A typical web page would redirect to a new page (thus dropping the socket.io connection) after logging out.

Comment: I see. Is this the typical way it is done? Would checking every emit be safer in case a hacker figures out how to keep the connection upon logout for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments following your question there are two items you can configure to better protect your users.

Tune your socket.io implementation:

1. Upgrade your socket.io implementation to use 2.x.
2. Make use of the 'socket.io#origins' configuration to eliminate the
   default CORS wildcard for any domain.
3. Use authenticated sessions within the socket.io connection. See
   'socket.io#adapter' or the 'session.socket.io' module alternative.

Tune your sites security headers:

1. Run your site (if publicly available) through
   https://securityheaders.com to test your current implementation.
2. Make use of the guide(s) at OWASP for more options regarding
   securing your site such as this one regarding use of the newer
   security headers available in browsers.
   https://www.owasp.org/index.php/List_of_useful_HTTP_headers

source : https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/89660/how-to-secure-my-node-js-socket-io-application-properly